# fancybox modal goes blank after jQuery .clone()

Tags: jquery, html, clone, fancybox-2

I've got a fancybox iframe that shows a form. Within the form I've got the following code...

```
<div class="subItem">
    <input type="text" class="form__textInput__field" name="subItems[]">
    <button class="clone">Add</button>
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

The idea is that the user will be able to click the "Add" and "Remove" buttons and clone the parent div and everything in it.

I've tried this two different ways. First, using clone as below.

```
$("button.remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
$("button.clone").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".subItem").clone().appendTo(".subItem");
});
```

Second, with a copy/paste of sorts.

```
$("button.remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
$("button.clone").click(function() {
    var content = $('.subItem').html();
    var newdiv = $('<div class="subItem">');
    newdiv.html(content);
    $('.subItem').after(newdiv);
});
```

In both of these instances, I can briefly see the new form field appear with the buttons, and then the modal goes completely blank. I have a feeling this is fancybox trying to prevent content from loading in case duplicate id's are brought in, but I'm not sure. How can I get this duplication to work?

Comment: Try using .clone(true,true)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - The result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this to get rid of the duplication of ids:

```
var $div = $('div[id^="subItem"]:last'); //look for the last object with the id "subItem"
var num = 2; //maybe you can use a random number to hang it on the id
var $klon = $div.clone().prop('id', 'subItem'+num ); //clone the div and give it another id
```

This works for me, when I clone some forms and need to be able to interact with them later.

Comment: There are no id's at play in my html.

Answer (score 0):

I feel foolish for even posting this question. Having not associated either of those buttons with anything other than the form that they were nested inside, it was causing a submit. I didn't dig into the html for the modal so I never saw the address it was pulling up. I changed these to div's and they're duplicating just fine now.